# Warn the developer while changing the param name

Tags: java, reflection, java-annotations

I am having a requirement where I need to fetch a param the value and validate before a method is invoked. I use MethodInterceptor (org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation) for this.

My method has three String parameters. I need to validate only the second parameter or specifically the parameter with the name `pname`. Currently, I use the following logic to validate the value of this parameter. But I have to hard code the param name or hardcode the index.

```
    int i=0;
    for(Parameter param: invocation.getMethod().getParameters()) {
     
        if(param.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("pname")) {
            //do validation using invocation.getArguments()[i]
        }
     i++;
    }
```

Either approach will fail if somebody modifies the method. Do we have a better approach or in worst case warn the future developer while he modifies the method param.

Comment: A parameter **annotation** might solve this better,

Comment: @JoopEggen can you please elaborate?

Comment: `void foo(int bar, @Baz String pname)` That is: not relying on the name. Quite traditional.

Comment: @JoopEggen.   I created an annotation with '@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)' and applied it on param. But params[i].getDeclaredAnnotation(MyParam.class) is returning null for all params! Where MyParam is the annotation class.

Comment: Is it a runtime annotation? `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`

Comment: Yes, it is a Runtime annotation. I got it working. thanks.